# Replace NAs of a particular variable with a particular value

Tags: r, na, missing-data

I have a dataset which looks like

```
Date       temperature   sysid      appliance_name 
01.03.18   13            abcd123    silverstar 320
02.03.18   15            abcd123    silverstar 320
03.03.18   17            abcd123    silverstar 320
04.03.18   15            abcd123    silverstar 320
01.03.18   18            bcfw5678   silverstar erp30i
02.03.18   14            bcfw5678   NA
03.03.18   18            bcfw5678   silverstar erp30i
04.03.18   10            bcfw5678   silverstar erp30i
01.03.18   16            ygft3456   NA
02.03.18   13            ygft3456   silverstar 30i
03.03.18   12            ygft3456   silverstar 30i
04.03.18   18            ygft3456   silverstar 30i
```

It is clear for me to fill the NAs with the same `appliance_name` as the `appliance_name` of a record with same `sysid`. For example, the record `02.03.18   14  bcfw5678   NA` should have the NA replaced with `silverstar erp30i` because from the other records it is clear that this particular `sysid` belongs to `silverstar erp30i`. I cannot use `do.locf` because it is possible that the previous record belongs to another appliance group.

What are the ways to  treat NAs in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to handle this is by replacing the `NA`'s by first non-NA value in each group (`sysid`).

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(sysid) %>%
  mutate(appliance_name = replace(appliance_name, is.na(appliance_name), 
                        appliance_name[which.max(!is.na(appliance_name))]))



#    Date     temperature sysid    appliance_name  
#   <fct>          <int> <fct>    <fct>           
# 1 01.03.18          13 abcd123  silverstar320   
# 2 02.03.18          15 abcd123  silverstar320   
# 3 03.03.18          17 abcd123  silverstar320   
# 4 04.03.18          15 abcd123  silverstar320   
# 5 01.03.18          18 bcfw5678 silverstarerp30i
# 6 02.03.18          14 bcfw5678 silverstarerp30i
# 7 03.03.18          18 bcfw5678 silverstarerp30i
# 8 04.03.18          10 bcfw5678 silverstarerp30i
# 9 01.03.18          16 ygft3456 silverstar30i   
#10 02.03.18          13 ygft3456 silverstar30i   
#11 03.03.18          12 ygft3456 silverstar30i   
#12 04.03.18          18 ygft3456 silverstar30i
```